# Adding data to existing row in new column for a TableLayout - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, tablelayout

So i have this interface where I add new items to the TableLayout when clicking the button. [See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p4iv.png)

The problem, as you see in the picture above, is that instead of adding the new items in the top of the third column it adds it as a new row in the third column. So new items should add linear to the second column in the third column when the listsize is higher than 5. I can only solve it with adding new rows. I dont know how to solve this in a good way.

Here is the code

```
fun addPlayerToTable(player: String) {

    //Create new Row and TextView
    val newRow = TableRow(this)
    val newText = TextView(this)

    var layoutParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    //Set text on ViewText
    newText.text = player

    if(players.size > 5){

        layoutParams.column = 2

    }else {
        layoutParams.column = 1
    }

    //Add TextViews and Rows dynamically
    newRow.addView(newText, layoutParams)
    table!!.addView(newRow)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I actually solved it. The fix was adding new TextViews and TableRows along some conditions. And also remove the views from index 1-6 since we dont want to remove the 0 index. It can probably be done way more simple though.

```
 fun addPlayerToTable(player: String) {

    //Create new Row and TextView
    var newRow = TableRow(this)
    var newText = TextView(this)
    var list = mutableListOf<TableRow>()
    var texts = mutableListOf<TextView>()

    if(players.size > 5){

        for(i in 0 until players.size){
            list.add(TableRow(this))
            texts.add(TextView(this))
            texts[i].text = players[i]
        }
    }

    var layoutParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    layoutParams.column = 1
    //Set text on ViewText
    newText.text = player

    if(players.size > 5){

        for(i in 1 until 6){
            table!!.removeViewAt(1)

        }
        for(i in 0 until 5){
            if(i + 5 >= players.size){
                list[i].addView(texts[i], layoutParams)
                table!!.addView(list[i])
            }
            else{
                list[i].addView(texts[i], layoutParams)
                list[i].addView(texts[i+5], layoutParams)
                table!!.addView(list[i])
            }

        }

    }else {

        //Add TextViews and Rows dynamically
        newRow.addView(newText, layoutParams)
        table!!.addView(newRow)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout

After referencing this doc, I see you can explicitly set the index when using the "addView" method.

Use an if statement before you add the view to check if the layoutParams.column == 2, if it does than set the index value of addView to players.size - 5.

EDIT: If you are hoping to have a new column for every 5 players, than have a variable set to 5, multiplied by the number of columns and use that to subtract from the players.size.

ie. players.size is 20, the next player added will begin column #5. To get this player into row 1 or index 0, you will need to subtract 20 from players.size, if you multiply 5 by the number of columns and subtract 5 thereafter, you will easily achieve this result.

Comment: Thank you! Im able to start at another index but the problem is still that new rows are created. I tried to do a workaround where i clear the whole table when size is > 5. It still doesnt solve the problem, idk if the removeAllViews work as I want it. See code below.

Comment: Hey, see my latest post for a solution.

Comment: @axlb That seems like a decent little work around! I'll check out the docs some more if I get time today but I can't see why that wouldn't work as a permanent fix :) good find!